# Rotation Matrix4x4 with centerPoint

Tags: matrix, rotation

Anyone can explain me this operation inside the method that creates a rotation matrix4x4:

```
**float x = centerPoint.X * (1 - c) + centerPoint.Y * s;
float y = centerPoint.Y * (1 - c) - centerPoint.X * s;**
```

Below is the complet method:

```
public static Matrix4x4 CreateRotationZ(float radians, Vector3 centerPoint)
        {
            Matrix4x4 result;

            float c = MathF.Cos(radians);
            float s = MathF.Sin(radians);

            float x = centerPoint.X * (1 - c) + centerPoint.Y * s;
            float y = centerPoint.Y * (1 - c) - centerPoint.X * s;

            // [  c  s  0  0 ]
            // [ -s  c  0  0 ]
            // [  0  0  1  0 ]
            // [  x  y  0  1 ]
            result.M11 = c;
            result.M12 = s;
            result.M13 = 0.0f;
            result.M14 = 0.0f;
            result.M21 = -s;
            result.M22 = c;
            result.M23 = 0.0f;
            result.M24 = 0.0f;
            result.M31 = 0.0f;
            result.M32 = 0.0f;
            result.M33 = 1.0f;
            result.M34 = 0.0f;
            result.M41 = x;
            result.M42 = y;
            result.M43 = 0.0f;
            result.M44 = 1.0f;

            return result;
        }
```

I'm very confusing with that, is it something like decomposing vectors?

Comment: It's a composition of translation of center of rotation to origin, rotation, then the inverse translation. Any computer graphics text will cover this. This uses the ancient graphics convention of row vectors left-multiplied.  See [this Wolfram Alpha blurb](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B-x%2C-y%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%7B%7Bcos+t%2Csin+t%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B-sin+t%2Ccos+t%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2C0%2C1%7D%7D)

Comment: Amazing, thank you friend
works